# Are there simultaneous eigenstates of $L_x$ and $L_y$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

$L_x$ and $L_y$ don't commute since $[L_x,L_y] = i \hbar L_z$. From the uncertainty principle, we know that $\Delta L_x \cdot \Delta L_y \geq \frac{1}{2} \cdot |\langle i \hbar L_z  \rangle|$. There would be no simultaneous eigenstates of $L_x$ and $L_y$ if $\langle L_z \rangle$ was zero for all eigenstates of $L_x$ and $L_y$. Is it possible to show that ?

Otherwise I would be happy with an other explanation of why or why not there would be simultaneous eigenstates of $L_x$ and $L_y$.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/450956/if-l-z-has-a-0-eigenfunction-since-l-x-l-y-i-hbar-l-z-then-can-l)

Answer (score 3):

According to the closure relationship we have for any two components of the angular momentum:
$$[\hat{J}_i,\hat{J}_j]=i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}L_k\tag{1}$$
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is Levi-Civita symbol and the sum is understood over the repeated indexes. A non-zero commutator implies that there is no *common basis* of eigenvectors.

That said, common eigenstates *can* still exist: in this case  the state vector such that all components of angular momentum are zero. Please notice this happens only because the commutator is an operator: if it were a number  (I mean a multiple of the identity operator), *not a single* common eigenstate would be possible. This is the case of position and momentum. Consider the 1D case:
$$[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar\mathbb{1}\tag{2}$$
Suppose there exists a common eigenstate $|\alpha\rangle$ such that:
$$\hat{x}|\alpha\rangle=x|\alpha\rangle \\
\hat{p}|\alpha\rangle=p|\alpha\rangle$$
Then
$$[\hat{x},\hat{p}]|\alpha\rangle=xp|\alpha\rangle-px|\alpha\rangle=0$$
that is contradiction with $(2)$.

On the other hand if the commutator were an operator as in $(1)$ it could possibly be zero for that particular state, as it happens for angular momentum.

Comment: The first part of your answer is good but I don't think it's wise in the second part to use $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ as an example given it is plagued by subtleties with normalization and unboundedness.

Comment: Do you mean because their eigeinbases are non-normalizable states?

Comment: In part yes.  Also because *in finite dimensional spaces* as there is the contradiction of $\hbox{Tr}[\hat x,\hat p]=\hbox{Tr}(\hat x \hat p)-\hbox{Tr}(\hat p\hat x)=i\hbar \hbox{Tr}(\mathbb{1})$, whereas in infinite dimensional spaces of course this identity must be handled carefully because of the unbounded nature of the operators.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that $\langle \alpha\vert L_z\vert\alpha\rangle=0$ if $\vert\alpha\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $L_x$ OR an eigenstate of $L_y$.  Indeed, if it’s an eigenstate of $L_x$ then $\Delta L_x=0$ so the uncertainty relation yields
$$
0\times \Delta L_y=0\ge \frac{1}{2}\vert\langle \alpha\vert L_z\vert\alpha\rangle\vert \tag{1}
$$
which implies the right hand side (which is necessarily real and non-negative) must be $0$.  The same argument can be trivially modified to show the same result if $\vert\alpha\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $L_x$ instead.

I don’t know how this proves there are no simultaneous eigenstates of $L_x$ and $L_y$ and nothing in (1) prevents $\Delta L_y=0$.

The converse is not true: there are states with $\langle L_z\rangle=0$ which are not eigenstates of $L_x$ or $L_y$.

There is one state which is a simultaneous eigenstate of $L_x$ AND $L_y$: it is the $L=0$ state.

Now if you have a basis where $L_x$ is diagonal, then you can construct ladder operators $\tilde L_\pm$ in terms of $L_y$ and $L_z$, and in particular express $L_y$ as a combo of $\tilde L_\pm$, which do not act diagonally on the eigenstates of $L_y$.  The exception is (again) the $L=0$ state, which is killed by $\tilde L_\pm$.

Answer (score -1):

One tool for finding your way towards a proof is to construct some representation matrices for a few different $L_{x,y,z}$ and see how you feel about them. [Here’s a representation for spin two](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/468134/44126), which gives you a sense of how it goes. The size of the matrix is $2\ell+1$. The $z$-axis matrix has the eigenvalues on the diagonal already,

$$
L_z = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
\ell
\\ &\ell-1
\\ && \ddots
\\ &&& -\ell+1
\\ &&&& - \ell
\end{array}\right),
$$

and the raising and lowering matrices are one-off-the-diagonal,

$$
L_+ = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0& \sqrt{2\ell} & 
\\ &0& \sqrt{\cdots} &
\\ &&\ddots
\\ && \cdots & 0& \sqrt{2\ell}
\\ &&&&0
\end{array}\right)
\qquad
L_- = (L_+)^T
\renewcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|{#1}\right>}
$$

so that $L_\pm\ket{\ell,m} = \sqrt{\ell(\ell+1) - m(m\pm1)} \ket{\ell, m\pm1}$.
From these raising and lowering matrices $L_\pm$ you construct

\begin{align}
2 L_x &= L_+ + L_-
\\
2i L_y &= L_+ - L_-
\end{align}

and then just find the eigenvectors. [For spin-half](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/389957/44126) (which isn’t allowed for orbital angular momentum $L$, but the algebra is similar), the $x$-axis eigenvectors are ${1}\choose{\pm1}$, with eigenvalues $\pm1$, and the $y$-axis eigenvectors are $1\choose{\pm i}$, with eigenvalues $\pm i$. Those basis vectors are orthogonal to each other.  However, it *is* the case that the eigenstates of $\sigma_x$ have expectation value $\left<\sigma_y\right> = \left<\sigma_z\right> = 0$.